# How to arrange terraform files/modules properly

Tags: terraform

I have multiple re-usable `terraform` modules. And I am using re-using these modules for creating the same resources with different configs.

So my folder structure is like this:

```
modules/
    vpc
    subnet
    lb
    s3
main.tf
variables.tf
```

So within my `main.tf` I am using the above modules again and again (i.e, the each module is repeated/re-used more than 10 times)

So I was wondering is there a better way to arrange these modules within `main.tf` ?

As a suggestion, can I re-use these modules inside different terraform files as below and call those terraform files inside `main.tf` for better readability and understanding?

```
modules/
    vpc
    subnet
    lb
    s3
service_one.tf
service_two.tf
.
.
service_ten.tf
main.tf
variables.tf
```

And inside the `main.tf`, can I call these service_*.tf files so the `main.tf` will be much cleaner.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got it right. In general about structure: [TF Modules Structure](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/develop/structure.html).

Terraform treats everything in a folder as the content of a module. So of course you can create as many *.tf files as you like. You don't even have to reference/call them in the main.tf. All *.tf files in the main folder (without subfolders) make up the main module, each subfolder is automatically a child module. Think of it as if all *.tf files in a folder are merged into one big file.

In general I define only things needed for the operation of terraform in the main.tf, e.g. backend, terraform and provider versions etc.
Besides that I group resources either topic or service/product depending on what fits better to the project, e.g.:

```
rds.tf
ecs.tf
networking.tf
```

or

```
product1.tf (includes rds, lambdas etc. for product1)
product2.tf (includes rds, lambdas etc. for product2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is so helpful. btw, now that I have put everything in the `main.tf` and if I move service 1 related terraform code to another tf file, would it going to mess up with my remote state?

Comment: As long as you don't move them to a different module (i.e. subfolder) or you rename resources the state file should be fine. Terraform literally merges everything in one big file, so it makes no difference... ;) But try with one service and check the output of ```terraform plan```. Just to avoid errors.